# getAcroForm() method returning null values, but with PDFTextStripper I am able to read complete text

Tags: pdfbox

I have a PDF document I want to read fields of that document but `PDAcroForm` object is null from `docCatalog.getAcroForm();`. with `PDFTextStripper` I am able to get the complete pdf as text, but I want to read fields.

The document [is here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1nPPjh88sO4sSGkBRArCfBgbXicasJyTn).

Comment: Please add some core code logic you used, and language tag.

Comment: Please share the PDF. Maybe the fields were "flattened".

Comment: Actually I can't see any option to upload pdf file here. code i am using is as below : PDDocument pdDoc = null;
       try {
           pdDoc = PDDocument.load((new FileInputStream(new File("Application for Individual Life Insurance.pdf"))));
       } catch (IOException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace(); 
       }
       PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = pdDoc.getDocumentCatalog();
       PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();
       List fields = acroForm.getFields();

Comment: *"Actually I can't see any option to upload pdf file here."* - usually one uses a public file sharing service (Google drive, dropbox,...) and posts the url here.

Comment: @mkl: I admit there aren't many options when dealing with binary formats, but if the OP uses a file locker, the file will be deleted in the future, and at that point, the question may have to be deleted too. The key issue is whether the question is understandable without the binary file for readers to test themselves.

Comment: @halfer If get getAcroForm() then there are no fields. But the user believes that there are fields, so she/he saw something. Further analysis requires some knowledge of the PDF specification that goes further than the PDFBox API.

Comment: @halfer this is a typical question in which the op simply cannot appropriately describe the issue of the binary file because he only observes the symptoms (file is not processed as desired) but does not understand the cause in his case. Furthermore, an answer cannot be given based on those symptoms alone because there are multiple possible causes, some of them incorrect assumptions about the file in question or the functionality of the library, others bugs either in the file or the library. A proper answer eventually will contain a description of the problematic property of the pdf file.

Comment: @mkl: you're probably right - I wonder if this is just a category of questions that should be thought of as temporary. It seems to work against the Stack Overflow principle that questions are forever, unless SO supplies a binary CDN that works in the same way as their image server (not on the horizon as far as I know). There's probably a _Meta_ question in here somewhere... `:-)`

Comment: sharing link of pdf :  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1nPPjh88sO4sSGkBRArCfBgbXicasJyTn

Comment: Yeah it's a flattened acroform. I.e. the content streams from the fields were moved to the general content stream, and the field structures were removed. So you can only extract with textstripper, or the area text stripper, or some forms recognition tool.

Answer (score 1):

The PDF you shared does *not* contain any AcroForm form fields.

If you inspect the file using a PDF browser (like iText RUPS or PDFBox PDFDebugger), you'll see that the **Catalog** only contains a **Pages** and a **Type** entry:

[image: Catalog screen shot]

In particular, there is no **AcroForm** entry which bundles the data of an AcroForm form. Thus, `docCatalog.getAcroForm();` cannot return any existing field structure.

Looking at the last **Contents** stream of e.g. page 1, one sees

```
Q
q
Q
q
1 0 0 1 329.78 655.45 cm
/Xi5 Do
Q
q
Q
q
1 0 0 1 324.17 624.51 cm
/Xi8 Do
Q
q
Q
q
1 0 0 1 265.95 702.31 cm
/Xi10 Do
Q
q
Q
q
1 0 0 1 554.46 655.6 cm
/Xi17 Do
Q
...
```

This is typical for a PDF which *used to contain* an AcroForm form definition which then was *flattened* into the page contents, for each former form field an XObject (which before defined the appearance of the form field widget annotation) is now referenced directly from the page content stream.

Thus, the only way to extract contents is via text extraction.

---

The obvious problem with text extraction is that it may be difficult to differentiate between former field contents and static form text like labels. Depending on the number of PDFs you have to extract data from it might be worth extending the `PDFTextStripper` to add some marker for text extracted from some XObject contents (in contrast to immediate page contents). Such markers would allow you to differentiate quite well.